# Random squares with symetrical ones inside

Tags: java, random, graphics, jframe, paint

So I have to draw 4 squares and then 10 random squares inside of each of the squares with random x and y coordinates and they have to be symetrical and then draw the whole screen with them side by side. Each section(4 large squares is a section) has to have the same random squares and in the same color. I have gotten to the point where I can draw a single section but can't think of anything to make them be drawn over and over so they cover the whole screen with the same random squares and random colors. Hope you understood it. Here is what I have right now.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    int a=100;
    Random rand = new Random();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(50, 50, a, a);
    g.drawRect(50+a, 50, a, a);
    g.drawRect(50, 50+a, a, a);
    g.drawRect(50+a, 50+a, a, a);
    int r = rand.nextInt(a/2);
    int rx = rand.nextInt(a/2)+50;
    int ry = rand.nextInt(a/2)+50;
    int rxsim = (2*a+50)-(rx-50)-r;
    int rysim = (2*a+50)-(ry-50)-r;
    g.setColor(new Color(rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255)));
    g.fillRect(rx, ry, r, r);
    g.fillRect(rxsim, ry, r, r);
    g.fillRect(rx, rysim, r, r);
    g.fillRect(rxsim, rysim, r, r); 
}
```

Comment: could you perhaps provide a picture that would explain your problem more?

Comment: @SaraSeppola I have it as [this](http://i.imgur.com/3XG2qUK.png)  but need to make it look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/R1Ue4bO.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can measure the size of your screen (or your frame, whatever) and the size of your rectangle

```
int widthScreen = getWidth();//TODO implement this
int widthSample = getSampleWidth();//TODO implement that (looks like 50 in your code)
```

once you know your sizes you calculate:

```
int amountHorizontal = widthScreen / widthSample + 1; //adding one extra
```

of course you must do the same with the amountVertical as well, it's same technique...

then you draw it dx/dy times

```
Graphics g; //your graphics to draw on
Rectangle r; //a rectanlge to be drawn
for(int dy = 0; dy < amountHorizontal; dy++){
    for(int dx = 0; dx < amountHorizontal; dx++){
        if(dx%2 == 0 && dy%2 == 0){ //even & even
            drawUpperLeft(r, dx, dy, g)
        }
        if(dx%2 != 0 && dy%2 == 0){ //odd & even
            drawUpperRight(r, dx, dy)
        }
        if(dx%2 == 0 && dy%2 != 0){ //even & odd
            drawLowerLeft(r, dx, dy)
        }
        if(dx%2 != 0 && dy%2 != 0){ //odd & odd
            drawLowerRight(r, dx, dy)
        }
    }
}
```

this is an example of how to implement one draw Method:

```
private void drawLowerRight(Rectangle r, int xOff, int yOff, Graphics g){

    //you already know how to rotate a rectangle by 90/180/270 degree
    Rectangle rot = createRectanlge(r, 270); 

    int x = xOff * widthSample;
    int y = yOff * widthSample;

    rot.x = rot.x + xOff;       
    rot.y = rot.y + yOff; 

    g.drawRect(rot);
}
```